# Integral with two parameterized constraints on upper bound

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, expectation

I'm stumped by a number of problems that come up in my probability studies: when there is an integral involving two random variables `(X,Y)` and the upper bound on one of the random variables (`Y`) is constrained by more than one variable expressions. Here's a typical scenario:

> Select a point `(X, Y)` at random from the circle:
>   $$
> \{\ (X, Y)\ |X^2 + Y^2| < 1\ \}
> $$
>   Compute `E(|X − Y|)`, i.e. the expectation of the absolute value of the difference of X and Y.

It seems to me as if I need:

$$
\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2<1}{|x-y|f(x,y)dxdy}
$$

...which I translate (perhaps myopically) into the following:

$$
\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2<1,\ \ y<x}{(x-y)f(x,y)dxdy} + \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2<1,\ \ x<y}{(y-x)f(x,y)dxdy}
$$

I don't know if that last step was the right move, but when I try to proceed with the first half of the previous expression, I have no idea how to set the upper bound because `y < x` *and* `y^2 < 1 - x^2`:

$$
\int_{-1}^1dx \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{?}(x-y)f(x,y)dy
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{(x,y):-1{\le}y{\le}x{\le}1, x^2+y^2{\le}1\}$ is $\{(x,y):-\sqrt{\tfrac 12}{\le}x{\le}1, -\sqrt{1-x^2}{\le}y{\le}\min\{x,\sqrt{ 1-x^2}\}\}$

This is the union: $$\{(x,y):-\sqrt{\tfrac 12}{\le}x{\le}\sqrt{\tfrac 12}, -\sqrt{1-x^2}{\le}y\le x\}\cup\{(x,y):\sqrt{\tfrac 12}{<}x{\le}1, -\sqrt{1-x^2}{\le}y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$$

[View the interval in question.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By%3D-sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%2C+y%3Dmin%5Bx%2C+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%5D%7D+%7C+x+from+-1+to+1)

Thus what you want is the sum of two integrals. $$\begin{align}
\iint_{-1\le y\le x\le 1, x^2+y^2\le 1}(x-y)f_{X,Y}(x,y) \operatorname d(x,y) & =
 \int_{-\sqrt{1/2}}^{\sqrt{1/2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^x (x-y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname dy \operatorname dx \\ & +\int_{\sqrt{1/2}}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (x-y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname dy \operatorname dx\end{align}$$

---

Do likewise for the other interval , $\{(x,y):-1{\le}x{<}y{\le}1, x^2+y^2{\le}1\}$

Or just declare an equality via symmetry.

---

PS: Have you worked out what the density function, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, is yet?

Comment: I suppose that $f_{X,Y} = \frac{1}{\pi}$?